# URL Rewrite mod with internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?pg=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?pg=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule . index.php?pg=home [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

tell me internal server error how to solve this problem.help me.

Comment: Consult the error.log.

Comment: … most likely you will find a message about too many redirects there.

Comment: Let us know which URL are you trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

Add another one, on top of all others:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
```

It will end the redirects loop once `index.php` is "found"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely reason of 500 is infinite looping. Add this rule just below `RewriteBase /project/` to prevent rewriting for files and directories.

```
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```